# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbs1056212.User_Logs' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL file that have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `Task_type` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Task_type`
--

INSERT INTO `Task_type` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 'Task', NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Meeting', NULL, NULL),
(3, 'Phone call', NULL, NULL),
(4, 'Task', NULL, NULL),
(5, 'Meeting', NULL, NULL),
(6, 'Phone call', NULL, NULL);

--
-- Table structure for table `User_logs`
--

CREATE TABLE `User_logs` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `login` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `logout` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `logged_out` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `User_logs`
--

INSERT INTO `User_logs` (`id`, `user_id`, `login`, `logout`, `time`, `logged_out`) VALUES
(42, 2, '2020-10-14 16:12:37', '2020-10-14 19:09:14', '2020-10-14 16:09:08', 1),
(43, 2, '2020-10-14 20:10:38', '2020-10-15 00:43:04', '2020-10-14 21:43:04', 0),
(44, 1, '2020-10-14 20:46:10', '2020-10-14 20:56:36', '2020-10-14 17:56:17', 1),
(45, 1, '2020-10-14 21:03:09', '2020-10-14 21:06:15', '2020-10-14 18:06:15', 0),
(46, 2, '2020-10-15 07:15:30', '2020-10-15 07:24:38', '2020-10-15 04:19:29', 1),
(47, 2, '2020-10-15 07:24:49', '2020-10-15 07:49:45', '2020-10-15 04:48:48', 1),
(48, 2, '2020-10-15 07:51:25', '2020-10-15 07:57:36', '2020-10-15 04:57:36', 0),
(49, 2, '2020-11-01 21:43:35', '2020-11-01 22:02:26', '2020-11-01 20:02:26', 0);
```

But, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbs1056212.User_Logs' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `User_Logs` (`user_id`, `logged_out`) values (1, 0))

I have been told that the table names should start with capital letters and the part after the dash is ok to start with lower case letter, and as you see table `Task_types` naming strategy, create, and insert are exactly the same as `User_logs` and it is not raising any exception, only table `User_logs` are raising this issue.

what to do?

database is MySQL

Comment: `User_logs` and `user_logs` are not necessarily the same (it actually depends on your underlying operating system.  Be consistent with capitalization.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a59713e52283b1c42e39963b27cb0e72 Is there another detail in your case you aren't showing?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I use INSERT INTO `User_logs`, and CREATE TABLE `User_logs` which should match, are not they?

Comment: @stickybit my os is windows 10 and is not showing the issue, while the issue raises on my team mate and he is using Linux

Comment: @mark15987: Hmm, looking closer at it, the code you've posted and the error message you posted don't correspond. Note that `insert` in the error message is in lower case but in the code you've posted it's in upper case. Further more in the error message only the columns `user_id` and `logged_out` are inserted. In your code they're much more. Review this and [edit] the question to also show the code that is actually producing the error.

Comment: Not just the OS, it depends on how you configure the RDBMS,  SQL Server can be both case sensitive and case insensitive depending on how the collation is set and at what level,  I assume mysql can be configured similarly.

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the table as `User_logs`.

The error message says it cannot find `User_Logs`.

These are not the same, because the case of the "l" is different.  Sometimes this makes a difference in MySQL, sometimes it doesn't depending on the value of a system variable [`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names).

The important consideration is deep in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html):

> Value 0 . . . Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. **Name comparisons are case sensitive**.

This is the default setting for the system variable `lower_case_table_names` on Unix systems (but not on MacOs which is Unix-like).  You can override it when creating the database, but that is rather unusual.